# How use numeric input in another ui pickerInput choice?

Tags: r, shiny

In shiny, i need to select a numeric range and use it as a choice in another pickerInput.

First i have:

```
               sliderTextInput(
                inputId = "size.range",
                label = "Choose a value:", 
                choices = c(1:100),
                selected =c(18,24),
                grid = TRUE )
```

and after i have:

```
                      pickerInput(
                       inputId = "sample.histoall",
                       label = "Selected Size",
                       choices = list( XXXXXX ),
                       options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                       multiple = TRUE)
```

with what I replace XXXXXX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the values of your numeric range and update your `pickerInput` on every change. You can choose to show the two returned values or the range between the returned values in your `pickerInput`. I added both options in the example below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderTextInput(
    inputId = "size.range",
    label = "Choose a value:", 
    choices = c(1:100),
    selected =c(18,24),
    grid = TRUE ),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "sample.histoall",
    label = "Selected Size",
    choices = list( '' ),
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
    multiple = TRUE),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "sample.histoall.range",
    label = "Selected Size",
    choices = list( '' ),
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
    multiple = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updatePickerInput(session, 'sample.histoall', choices=input$size.range)
    updatePickerInput(session, 'sample.histoall.range', choices=as.numeric(input$size.range[1]):as.numeric(input$size.range[2]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```